# macro error: A character operand was found in the %EVAL function or %IF condition

Tags: macros, sas, sas-macro

```
%macro test(k);

%if &k le 0 %then %put < 0 ;
%else %put > 0;
%mend test;
%test(-5); 
%test(3.1);
```

But `%test(-3.1);` will generate error

```
ERROR: A character operand was found in the %EVAL function or %IF condition where a numeric operand is required. The condition was: 
       &k le 0
```

I have no idea why this simple value comparison will lead to error. At first I guess it's because `.`. But inputing 3.1 seems everything goes well.

Comment: `%sysevalf(&k le 0)` solves this. But why `-5` don't need `sysevalf`?

Comment: Code is fine. I do not see any reason that it should not work. Probably restart the application and try again

Comment: Agree with NEOmen, the code is fine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The macro %IF statement implicitly calls the %EVAL() function.  %EVAL() understands integers (whether positive or negative), but not decimal values.  When %EVAL() compares two values, if one of them is a decimal it will do a CHARACTER comparison.  So %IF (3.1>10) returns true.  If you give %EVAL a decimal with a negative sign in front of it (-3.1), it errors, because it thinks 3.1 is character not a number, so the - sign must be the subtraction operator, and then you are trying to subtract character values.  Below are some examples of playing with %eval().

```
%put %eval(10   > 2) ;   /*true: numeric comparison*/
%put %eval(10.1 > 2) ;   /*false: character comparison*/

%put %eval(-2   > -5 ) ; /*true: numeric comparison*/
%put %eval(2.0  > -5 ) ; /*true: character comparison*/

%put %eval(+10 > +2 ) ; /*true: numeric comparison*/
%put %eval(-10 > +2 ) ; /*false: numeric comparison*/
%put %eval(10.1 > +20 ) ; /*false: character comparison (+20 is evaluated to 20) */
%put %eval(+10.1 >+20 ) ;  /*error: %eval() cant handle +10.1*/
%put %eval(-10.1 >+20 ) ;  /*error: %eval() cant handle -10.1*/

%put %eval(-2);    /* -2 */
%put %eval(+2);    /* 2 */
%put %eval(-2.1);  /*error*/
%put %eval(+2.1);  /*error*/
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use sysevalf to evaluate arithmetic and logical expressions using floating-point arithmetic. As you pointed out, `%sysevalf(&k le 0)` will solve the problem.